# Determining of tangent space in spaces of matrices

Tags: differential-geometry

Let M be a set of all matrices that have determinant equal to one. If we see all matrices $M_{n,n}$ of dimensions $n \times n$ as a manifold over $R^{n^2}$, then our M is submanifold. Now, let A be arbitrary element of M. Determine $T_A M$. Now, I tried to set $T_A M$ as something diffeomorphic to $R^{n^2}$ but I don't know if it is true, I am truly unconfident.

Comment: Consider a curve $\phi(t)$ of unit-determinant matrices through $A$, that is, with $\phi(0)=A$. Then use Jacobi's formula to say something about $\frac{d}{dt}\det{\phi(t)}$. You'll get something especially simple for $A=I$.

Comment: The set you are considering is a Lie group for multiplication, called the Special Linear Group. As encouraged to do by @symplectomorphic (thanks to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi's_formula which interconnects "determinant" and "trace"...), it suffices to understand how is build the tangent space in the identity matrix.

Comment: Hint: Your M is the special linear group. Prove that it can be constructed using the regular value theorem from the map $\det :{\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}} \to \mathbb{R}$. You can then use the fact that the tangent space of M at a point A is equal to the kernel of the differential of this map at A.

Comment: Since $M$ is a linear group (we usually write it as $SL(n, \Bbb R)$), we can identify $T_A M$ coincides with the pushforward of $T_I M$ by the linear map $T_I L_A$, where $L_A$ denotes the map $M \to M$ defined by left multiplication by $A$, but we can identify $T_I L_A$ with $A$ itself, so it's enough to compute $T_I M$.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really necessary to think about group stricture: multivariable calculus is enough. When $F:\mathbb{R}^N\to \mathbb{R}$ is a smooth function such that $\nabla F$ does not vanish on the set $F^{-1}( 1 )$, the set $F^{-1}(1)$ is a submanifold of dimension $N-1$ with the tangent space being the orthogonal complement of $\nabla F(x)$.

Here $N=n^2$ and $F$ is the determinant function. To find $\nabla F$, suppose $\det A=1$ and the entries of $B$ are small. Then
$$\det (A+ B) = \det (I+ A^{-1}B)$$  where the contribution of off-diagonal entries of $A^{-1}B$ is of second order of magnitude in $B$ (because when an off-diagonal entry appears in the computation of determinant, it is multiplied by another such entry). Therefore, the linear approximation to $\det (I+A^{-1}B)$ is just $1+\operatorname{tr}(A^{-1}B)$. Conclusion: 
$$
T_AM = \{B : \operatorname{tr}(A^{-1}B) = 0\}
$$